# How to make fields on webforms mandatory

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am registering for events through webforms. However if people do not leave their phone numbers we cannot contact them. Is there some options I am missing here to make this a mandatory field?

Comment: with a webform in Drupal you have the option to make any field in the form required (mandatory). This setting should be apparent from the list of webform components.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make a field mandatory in a webform. You will need to go under Webform tab of a webform. Click on edit besides the Phone field. On Edit phone scroll down till you see 'VALIDATION'. Check the 'Required' check box and save the form.

[image]